# Intellisense not working in visual studio 6?

Tags: vb6, intellisense

As I experienced a sudden nostalgic longing for the VB6 of old, I downloaded visual studio 6 from my msdn subscription. To revive my rusty knowledge I very much would like to have intellisense working, but it does not! Is this a known problem with VS6 on Windows 7? I do have the autocomplete option on in the Options menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS6 does work properly for me on Win7.

The only problem is that it fails to add a reference to a COM object/library because UAC prevents it from reading required registry keys. Maybe your problem has the same nature. Try to run the IDE elevated.

Comment: It suddenly started working, I think running VB6 elevated caused it.

Answer (score 2):

Try placing a check mark in:

Tools->Options->Editor->Auto List Members

Answer (score 0):

Once happened to me

I entered a line without Dim
N as integer

After I corrected it start working
Dim N as integer

Comment: please add more explanation to your content